# Posición ocupada Tres en raya JAVA

Tags: java, motor-de-juego

estoy haciendo un tres en raya pero tengo un problema, a la hora de colocar la ficha, **no reconoce que la posición está ocupada y la cambia continuamente.** ¿Qué puedo usar para que no suceda esto?
Dejo el código al completo. La función que me causa el problema es la de ***Rellenar()***:

```
package TresEnRaya;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Juego {

private String jugador, ficha;
private String[][] tablero = new String[3][3];
private int fila, columna;
private static boolean ganar = false;

protected String[][] CrearTablero() {

    for (int columna=0; columna<tablero.length; columna++) {
        for (int fila=0; fila<tablero.length; fila++) {
            tablero[columna][fila] = "·";
            System.out.print(tablero[columna][fila] +" ");
        }
    System.out.println("");}
    return tablero;
}


private void Jugador(String ficha, String jugador) {
    this.ficha = ficha;
    this.jugador = jugador;
}


protected void Rellenar() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce datos " + jugador);

    System.out.print("Columna: ");
    fila=reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Fila: ");
    columna=reader.nextInt();

    tablero[columna][fila] = ficha;

    if (tablero[columna][fila] == ficha) System.err.println("Posición ocupada");
    for (int col=0; col<tablero.length; col++) {
        for (int fil=0; fil<tablero.length; fil++) {
            System.out.print(tablero[col][fil]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println("");}
}


protected boolean ComprobarHorizontal() {

    for (int columna=0; columna<tablero.length; columna++) {
        for (int fila=0; fila<tablero.length; fila++) {
            if (tablero[columna][fila].equals(ficha)) {
                ganar = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return ganar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Juego jugar = new Juego();
    jugar.CrearTablero();

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        jugar.Jugador("x", "Unai");
        jugar.Rellenar();
        jugar.Jugador("o", "Contrario");
        jugar.Rellenar();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Qué es tablero? Como lo inicias? ficha que es, un objeto propio? Explica un poco más tu código. Además haces tablero[columna][fila] = ficha; y luego comparas si tablero[columna][fila] == ficha que debería ser siempre true, pero habría que ver como has definido tablero y ficha para ver si haces bien esas comparaciones

Comment: Como dice el compañero de arriba, explica un poco más tu código para que te podamos ayudar. Además, no entiendo porque pides la fila y recoges el valor en la variable columna y lo mismo haces con la columna, pides columna y recoges el valor en la fila.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano ya he puesto el código completo. Espero que os sirva de ayuda, y disculpad por la tardanza.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias cosas.

Lo primero, pides la columna y lo asignas a fila, lo mismo con la columna.
Después, Asignas el valor a la celda siempre y luego comparas. Primero tienes que consultar el valor de la celda y según lo que sea asignarle el valor o no.

```
protected void Rellenar() {
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Introduce datos " + jugador);

  System.out.print("Columna: ");
  columna=reader.nextInt();   //Antes asignabas este valor a fila

  System.out.print("Fila: ");
  fila=reader.nextInt();      //Antes asignabas este valor a columna

  if (tablero[columna][fila].Equals(ficha))  //Comprobamos que esté ocupada
    System.err.println("Posición ocupada");
  else
    tablero[columna][fila] = ficha  //Si no está ocupada, le asignamos el valor

  for (int col=0; col<tablero.length; col++) {
    for (int fil=0; fil<tablero.length; fil++) {
        System.out.print(tablero[col][fil]+" ");
    }
  System.out.println("");}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que tu if necesita un else. por eso te coloca siempre la ficha.

```
   protected void Rellenar() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce datos " + jugador);

    System.out.print("Columna: ");
    fila=reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Fila: ");
    columna=reader.nextInt();

    tablero[columna][fila] = ficha;

    if (tablero[columna][fila] == ficha) 
System.err.println("Posición ocupada");
else{
    for (int col=0; col<tablero.length; col++) {
        for (int fil=0; fil<tablero.length; fil++) {
            System.out.print(tablero[col][fil]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println("");}
}
}
```

Comment: No, no es el `else`.